# Update a p element from a nodejs function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

I need to send a value from a input form to a nodejs server, which triggers a calculation with this value and needs to update an p element with the result of the calculation on the client side.

How can this be done?

This is what i have:

//Server side:

```
    app.post('/calculate/:id', function(req, res){
    var title = 'Tax Calculation';
    var tax= taxcalculation(req.params.id);
    res.render('index', {
        title: title,
        tax: tax,
    });
});
```

//Client side:

```
var income= document.getElementById("income");
        var tax = document.getElementById("tax")
        $(income).on('change', function() {
            console.log("changed");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/calculate/'+income.value,
                success: function() {
                    $('#tax').html('<%= tax %>');
                },
                error: function() { // if error occured
                    alert("Error occured, please try again");
                },
            });              
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you don't give a lot of data, but this sounds as simple as sending a response with the results to the client side in your Node web service that does the calculations and append the result to the P element

Comment: I'm able to update the p element with a refresh of the page. How could i do this without refreshing the page?

Comment: When you get the response you can do something like this `document.getElementById("yourParagraph").innerHTML = response.data;`

Answer (score 0):

Your server code to handle the ajax call should output a json response which will contain the content for the `<p>`.  It should not re-render the whole index page.  I don't do a lot of node.js so I'll leave that for you to figure out.

The ajax success function should accept a response as a parameter, and then operate on that response.

Assuming the server response to this ajax request is of the format `{"tax": 15.99}`:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/calculate/'+income.value,
        success: function(response) {
          if (response.tax || response.tax === 0) {
            $('#tax').html(response.tax);
          }
        },
        error: function() { // if error occured
            alert("Error occured, please try again");
        },
    });
```